# Disable "questions need votes too" popup for users w/ Electorate badge

Tags: feature-request, voting, electorate-badge

Not sure if it would even be possible to base specific site functionality on a badge, but if it is..

What do you think about disabling the the *"You haven't voted on a question in a while.  Questions need votes too."* popup *ONLY* for users who have attained the [**Electorate**](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/155/electorate) badge?  Having this badge proves that the user understands the importance of voting on questions and does so often.

This idea came to mind while I was /review'ing first answers and late answers (which is why I had a stream of only answer votes).

> [**Electorate** - Voted on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions.](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/155/electorate)