# What badges unlock features?

Tags: discussion, badges

I took a peek at the Review tab and I noticed this:

[image]

I love the idea of badges unlocking certain features. Do any other badges do this? I think it's a great way to deepen the engagement of badges.

Comment: I would assume it's really your editing activities that unlock both the badge and the ability to review, but it's presented this way to keep things simple -- whether you have a badge is much easier to keep track of than your number of edits, especially since you can't find out how many you currently have that count.

Comment: This would kind of be like unlocking a feature: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111459/disable-questions-need-votes-too-popup-for-users-w-electorate-badge

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is the unique badge that requires you to first have another badge, to be able to gain it. There are other badges that you gain after you gained another badge, such as the [Copy Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/223/copy-editor) that is gained after the [Strunk & White](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/12/strunk-white), but in those cases there isn't an explicit requirement to gain first one, and then the other badge.

Answer (score 6):

At the moment, there are not. However, there are several badges which you cannot earn until you've earned certain other badges, simply because they're for doing the same action a different number of times. Examples: Enthusiast/Fanatic, Supporter/Suffrage.